# IEnumerable needs to be sorted before using Enumerable.Distinct?

Tags: c#

Will the `Enumerable.Distinct` method remove all duplicates from a collection implementing `IEnumerable` even if it is not sorted?

I'm coming from a C++ background and wonder if `Distinct` behaves similiar to C++ [unique algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) where the sequence has to be sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the Enumerable.Distinct method remove all duplicates from a
>   collection implementing IEnumerable even if it is not sorted?

Yes.

Note that you need to implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface and it's `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for custom types.